# is there any good Http library for React flux architecture

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux, reactjs-flux

We have a react application with Flux architecture, I am searching any good library for sending http request like angular's $http, $resources.

Answer (score 20):

You don't need something specific for React or Flux, you can use a regular CommonJS module. There are several you can use, my favourites are:

- [Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent): small, easy to use and easily extensible via plugins
- [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios): really nice implementation of the Promise API and Client side support for protecting against [XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (plus supports IE8)
- [Fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch): built by Github so support is pretty good

All the links include installation and usage

Comment: Thanks **emilioicai** I like Axios. Is it supports all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the `whatwg-fetch` you have to install it using

```
$ npm install whatwg-fetch --save
```

for more information please refer [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: I think fetch is a good choice, because it's the future and a polyfill should work just fine for the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

the best http library for react and for js - `isomorphic-fetch`, it works in all browsers, have small size and have promises support

https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

not use:

- `axios` library have big size
- `request` library does not have support promises
- `native fetch` does not have support all browsers